# How to export slots and accessors from Lisp classes?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, clos

This is my class's package:

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(defpackage foo
  (:use :cl)
  (:export :bar))
(in-package :foo)

(defclass bar ()
  (baz))
```

I can create an instance of `bar` in package `cl-user`.

```
CL-USER> (defvar f)
F
CL-USER> (setf f (make-instance 'foo:bar))
#<FOO:BAR {10044340C3}>
```

But I can't access the member `baz`. Calling `slot-value` like so ...

```
CL-USER> (slot-value f 'baz)
```

... results in this error message:

```
When attempting to read the slot's value (slot-value), the slot
BAZ is missing from the object #<FOO:BAR {10044340C3}>.
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]
```

I already tried to add `baz` to the `:export` list but that does not work either.

How to export slots and accessors from packages?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't *export* slots and accessors.

In Common Lisp you can export symbols.

So, export the symbol `BAZ` which names the slot.

Then in package `CL-USER`:

```
(slot-value some-instance 'foo:baz)
```

Unexported you have to write:

```
(slot-value some-instance 'foo::baz)
```

If you import the symbol into the package `CL-USER`:

```
(slot-value some-instance 'baz)
```